# Typeguard validation of object with incorrect children fields

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typeguards

The following code validates the object 'Discharge' and is intended to check if the object contains the correct children fields.

```
interface DischargeEntry {
  date: string;
  criteria: string;
}

const isDischargeEntry = (discharge:unknown): discharge is DischargeEntry => {
  
  return (
          (((discharge as DischargeEntry).date) !== undefined) ||
          (((discharge as DischargeEntry).criteria) !== undefined)
         );
  
}

const incorrectDischarge:unknown = {
  criteria: "Thumb has healed."
};

console.log('isDischargeEntry:', isDischargeEntry(incorrectDischarge)) // = true (but should be false)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCLAM4IBZygcwgFFwoBPZAbwChlkATOSALmQzClHwG5bkFOkTnFbtOIHtQC%201aggD2IdskzosuAsVIUAvMgAU9TDjyFmAVxABrEPIDuIAJSsj60ykxpjGwiQ66APio%20PigIMHMoEAM%20Oji4-UTXE01kOAwvN00-ckcAOkZIR2QAQh09S3oIGFAIemKAHwbY%20ISk73c0jLUU3218gWAhYDhisoqQKpqQOscW1sdeOmlZBSUwFRAFKDCEMB6fCAtrWwdkPRo6QeGRZAAiABVscwBbACNkXAzsCDgAGzqeTu0l4ckUGHkALyf3k%20H0AHJVB1stpmPCADQqDAHdw5Mj6UDbXb7ZGERzFAD0FPOyA45hQ%20je5g2GGw8nMf3oyDeKHgfwwEEcQA)

Is something wrong in the boolean condition inside the return or maybe the 'as' keyword is altering the logic?

Comment: Shouldn't it be an `&&` condition since both properties are required??

Answer (score 0):

If both properties are required, the conditions need to be combined using `&&` to create a logical AND.

```
const isDischargeEntry = (discharge:unknown): discharge is DischargeEntry => {
  
  return (
          (((discharge as DischargeEntry).date) !== undefined) 
          &&
          (((discharge as DischargeEntry).criteria) !== undefined)
         );
  
}
```